# Peewee Python ORM: assign query result to ForeignKeyField

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I have 2 models with a dead-simple one-to-many relationship. I'm trying to assign the result of querying one of them into the other entity, but I don't know how to do it. This is the code:

The main class inherit from 2 classes, and has also the `__init__` method overloaded

```
class Bot(MySQLDatabase, ClientXMPP):
    room = ForeignKeyField(Room)
```

At some point I query and try to assign:

```
def __init__(self, ..., ..., room):
    DBConnection.connect()

    self.room = Room.get(...)
    self.save()
```

But it throws me this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    xmpp = Bot(..., ..., room)
  File "/home/.../bot.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.room = room
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 724, in __set__
    instance._data[self.att_name] = value.get_id()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

I just started using this library, so this is probably due to a misunderstanding of the documentation.

Comment: Could you give more detail of your model especially class of Room?. Otherwise, i bet you already know [this](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#looking-at-some-simple-queries)

Comment: I'm updating the post to add more information. I don't think the structure of Room is relevant (after all, it is a simple class with properties), but as I am using multiple inheritance with overloaded __init__ methods, it seems the issue is coming from there.

Comment: Sorry, I think you need post your Model more clearly here. Anyway, try simple query of peewee with [this documentations](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#looking-at-some-simple-queries).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but in case someone else is getting this error I found this link: [Peewee models perform initialization on startup](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/118) and therefore you must call super in any peewee model constructor.

So,

```
def __init__(self, ..., ..., room):
   DBConnection.connect()

   self.room = Room.get(...)
   self.save()
```

would become:

```
def __init__(self, ..., ..., room):
   super(Bot, self).__init__()
   DBConnection.connect()
   self.room = Room.get(...)
   self.save()
```